# Picasso get jpeg decoding error on mobile network

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, decoding, skia

I'm making the wallpaper and have an error while loading image using Picasso on mobile network, important thing that the same image is loading perfectly via wi-fi! 
I have added the bigger timeout but problem is still percist:

```
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            Picasso    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(LiveService.this)
                    .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
                    .build();
            try{
            bitmap = picasso.with(LiveService.this)
                    .load(url)
                    .get( );

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("TAG", "Load IOException");

            }
```

This is logcat:

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
05-02 23:32:07.630 4704-8037/jpro.com.Servicelive W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Failed to decode stream.
05-02 23:32:07.631 4704-8037/jpro.com.Servicelive W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:145)
05-02 23:32:07.631 4704-8037/jpro.com.Servicelive W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
05-02 23:32:07.631 4704-8037/jpro.com.Servicelive W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:396)
```

I'm testing on Doogee x5max with 6 Android. Image is not big 550x550 px and another images from different servers has the same error.
I have tried the Glide library and get the same error on mobile network so I have to returned back to Picasso.
 I think the problem is in mobile connection but if timeout doesn't help then how to fix it?

Comment: if someone will have the same problem: I have tried to "increase buffer "in BitmapHunter class of Picasso as many advised in other topics:

from   private static final int MARKER = 65536;
to      private static final int MARKER = 131072;

i did it but it wasn't worked for me.
I'll continue to search the way to fix.